# Rules- how to perform processing on cancelled accounts?

Tags: rules

I have my site configured to allow users to cancel their accounts, in which case the account is blocked and the content is unpublished.  I made a rule to act on the **Event** *after a user account has been deleted*, but my actions are not performed when a user cancels his/her account.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of configuration, you need to use the **Event** *After updating a user account* with the conditions *User is blocked* (account) and *NOT User is blocked* (account-unchanged).